# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping

Tags: swift

why I am getting Thread 1:EXE_BAD_INSTRUCTION

this is my code

```
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    var fileclocaiton = NSString(string: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(self.navigationItem.title, ofType: "mp3")!)
    var error: NSError? = nil
    player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: fileclocaiton as String), error: &error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var fileclocaiton = NSString(string: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(self.navigationItem.title, ofType: "mp3")!)
```

This line is the source of crash. Are you sure that you have the same resource as your navigationItem.title is ? Is navigationItem.title same as title property on UIViewController ? That you have to try out and make sure that the resource of that type exist. You could avoid crash in case the resource is not found using if let as,

```
if let fileclocaiton = NSString(string: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(self.navigationItem.title, ofType: "mp3")) {

     ... do rest of your coding here.
}
```

Comment: You are right about binding the fileLocation, but it can be further improved using the URLForResource(_:withExtension:) method on NSBundle since the AVPlayer requires a URL. Saves having to bind a second time on the failable NSURL initializer.